# Is my wire rated at a high enough current?

Tags: amplifier, resistance, wire, speakers, ohms-law

I am in the process of planning a speaker build. I am making sure my current wiring is up to the demands of a new system. The amplifier is a CV 1800, which can put out 9.5 amps at 4 ohms in stereo (600 watts) or 19.5 amps at 4 ohms in a bridged mono setting (1800 watts). I am wondering what it would put out at 3 ohms. I am lost as how to calculate this, as I don't think it follows any basic V=IR, P=VA equations that I could use in an ideal situation. 
The wire I'm using is rated at 300 volts and 12 amps. Would this be adequate for use at 3 ohms? (I'd also guess the wire is about 50 ft)

The wire: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2335141.pdf

The amplifier data sheet (The Cerwin Vega website isn't responding to me):
https://mans.io/item/cerwin-vega/cv-1800
or, just search cv 1800 data sheet

Comment: 12 gauge wire will not have any problem with 9.5A as far as heating goes. Even 19.5A would be OK as long as it is not continuous (which it won't be, for audio). I am not sure about the sound quality implications. How long is the wire run?

Comment: If you are worried about wire INSIDE the speaker, just use much larger wire, or run several strands of the 12 gauge wire. If you are worried about the wire run between amp and speaker, you need to state how long the wire run is.

Comment: The wire would be somewhere around 50 feet if I had to guess because it's in the wall already O.o
What would be the max distance?
(and yes between the amp and speaker)

Comment: If it is in the wall already, then just try it out to see how it goes. I don't think there is any hazard. So it is only a matter of sound quality. There is a table on the wikipedia page for speaker wire. For 12AWG wire, they list 60 feet as the max. They are not considering current limits, but sound quality. Not sure how reliable it is, but I think it at least suggests you might be OK. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_wire

Comment: I was under the impression that running speaker wire at too high power will make the casing melt due to heat and could cause a fire?

Comment: Yeah. For sure. But 12 gauge wire is not going to get very hot with 20 Amps going through it. You can google "NEC ampacity table" for more information. If I was going to wire a 20A circuit, I would probably use 10 AWG wire, but seeing as how you already have 12 AWG in the wall, I would just go with that.

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying. The datasheet recommends max of 12A. BUT, it also says insulation is UL rated to 75C. NEC ampacity table for 75C insulation says you are allowed to run up to 25 Amps. So, from that perspective, you are fine. Also note that the datasheet indicates that the 12A limit is based on a 10C temperature rise. So you can expect that if you run at 20A for an extended period, the wire will probably get hot. But in an audio application, you are not going to operate at max current continuously. Melting and fire should not occur. But if you are worried, add a fuse in series.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help mkeith!! I'll look into a fuse knowing I'll probably be fine either way!!! If you'd like to post an answer, I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score -1):

I am by no means an audiophile/speaker designer, but with the numbers that you gave, I would say no. 9.5 amps @ 600 Watts through 4 ohms resistive equals 2.65 Ohms reactive. and 19.5 Amps @ 1800 watts through 4 Ohms resistive equals 0.73 Ohms reactive. The amp numbers at 3 Ohms instead of 4 would be 10.3 Amps @ 600 watts stereo and 21.97 Amps @ 1800 watts mono. If I am wrong on that, someone please let me know. I am not too familiar with speaker design, and it has been a year and a half since I took an AC course. 
In general, less resistance equals higher Amperage. In my opinion, the 12 Amp rating would be cutting it a little close for the 9.5 Amp stereo design. This might be common practice and generally accepted amongst speaker system designers, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: Your answer is gibberish and you say several times that you don't know what you're talking about, so do the decent thing and delete your answer please.